# Update links in post content

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i am getting links from post using `wp_extract_urls` and trying to update in content.

```
      $post_edit = get_post( $editID ); 
      $title = $post_edit->post_title;
      $content = $post_edit->post_content;
          $new_link= $_POST['link'];
          $old_link= $_POST['or_val'];
          foreach( $new_link as $key => $n ) {
              print "full link: ".$n." <br> Short Link: ".$or_val[$key];
              $content = str_replace($old_link[$key], $n, $content);
            }
```

Getting error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 421888 bytes) in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 809

Comment: What line is 809?

Comment: error in wp_extract_urls() function

Comment: This does not help debugging. Show the line of code which is affected. As the error says, PHP wants to allocate more memory, but it is limited to 256 MB. Maybe you need just to increase that.